# Insert XML node value inside iframe src

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, iframe

Been trying everything and all i get is a blank page ...

The XML is provided by URL format and contains many nodes but i just want to take out the username and place it inside a iframe scr url.

optimal this will repeat for until no more usernames on that xml

Here is what i got so far

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    //Code for IE7,Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    //code for IE6,IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://xml.url/here", false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
y=xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;
for (i=0;i<y.length;i++)
{
    if (y[i].nodeType!=3)
    {
        //This code for printing attribute of a tag(you have to give attribute name).
        document.write("<br>" + y[i].getAttributeNode('username').nodeName + ":  ");
        document.write(y[i].getAttributeNode('username').nodeValue + "<br>");
        for (z=0;z<y[i].childNodes.length;z++)
        {
            if (y[i].childNodes[z].nodeType!=3)
            {
                            //This is for Node Name.
                document.write(y[i].childNodes[z].nodeName + ": ");
                            //This is for Node Value.
                document.write(y[i].childNodes[z].textContent + "<br>");
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>

<iframe src="http://blablabla + 'username' + blablabla " height="300" width="400" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```